# whether this is a valid getJSON() in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, getjson

I am using asp.net mvc with jquery... I have made a json call to a controller method and it returns json object `[Object object]` for me. I dont want that instead i want to get the json string... Any suggestion...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('Materials/GetMaterials', null, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
```

I gave `alert(data.d);` and it is `undefined`

```
  public JsonResult GetMaterials()
    {
        var materials = consRepository.FindAllMaterials().AsQueryable();
        return Json(materials);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getJSON will return a json object. If that isn't what you want you shouldn't use it. You can use $.ajax instead and set the content type to text/plain and you will receive the data as a string. I can't, however, see any reason you would want to work with a string instead of a object.

You can optionally use the JSON.stringify method from the json2 library to turn a object into a string.

Comment: @Mattias Ok how can i iterate through json object... Consider 10rows containing `UserName` and `EmailId`.... I want iterate these object with `<td>data.Username</td>` and `<td>data.EmailId</td>`

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur, of course that is possible. You have a for loop in javascript you can use. jQuery has a each method that loops over a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('Materials/GetMaterials', null, function(data) {

        $.each(data , function(index,d) {
            alert(d.Id)
        });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using console.log (+ use firebug or web inspector) instead of alert(). You'll be able to expand the returned json object's structure and determine how to access the data you're after.